# Recognize user cut/swipe gesture (UISwipeGestureRecognizer)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uicontrol

I use below code and work for 'self.view' but doesn't work for imageview and for direction just can add one direction how to use four direction(right,left,uo,down)?

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:selfaction:@selector(sr)];
swipe.direction =UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[imageview addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
[swipe release];
```

Comment: What does it mean to cut a view?

Comment: Means start touching for example from left side to right side of control

Comment: That's not exactly what we call it in the iPhone world... Or at least I've never heard it said that way

Comment: like cut fruits in "Fruit Ninja" or cut ropes in "Cut the rope"

Comment: Let me take a swipe at it: In the iPhone world this is called a "SWIPE".

Comment: Oh, but might I recommend you edit the title so other users are less confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with your app only running on iOS 3.2+, the best way to do this is to use the `UIGestureRecognizer` API class.  In fact, there is a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` subclass ([docs are here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer)).

To do what you want, do something like this:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
[swipe release];
```

To change to any other direction, look at the docs link above - there is a constant with all four directions.

Comment: Thank you,i use this code and works for 'self.view' but doesn't work for 'imageview'

Comment: Hey if u got solution of it than u can put it in answer... because same problem i face in imageView gesture works on lable , view etc.... please send solution of it if u got it

Answer (score 2):

Delegates

```
touchesBegan: 

touchesEnded:
```

Answer (score 2):

//--------add this code in the imageview allocation-------//

```
        imageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

for four direction you have to use two UISwipeGestureRecognizer:-

```
      UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightLeft =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer     alloc]initWithTarget:selfaction:@selector(sr)];

   [swipeRightLeft setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight |UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft )];

   [imageview addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightLeft];

    [swipeRightLeft release];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUpDown =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer     alloc]initWithTarget:selfaction:@selector(sr)];

      [swipeUpDown setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown )];

    [imageview addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpDown];

    [swipeUpDown release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling interaction:

```
yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

and add some directions, something like this:

```
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
```